# Powerpoint change table formation in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to edit a table in a slide, and I am using this code but it takes a lot of time to complete.

```
For lRow = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
For lCol = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
With oTbl.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
.Font.Name = "Arial"
.Font.Size = 30
End With
Next
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting table in powerpoint macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821984/formatting-table-in-powerpoint-macro)

Comment: This is the correct way to change properties in the .Font object within a table. I use this method a lot and never found it to take a long time but that may be a relative perception e.g. 0.1s is long compared to 1ns so how many cells are there, how long is it taking and what target time are you looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this code can help you. It will change format in each table of active presentation. You just have to update Font Name and Font Size.

Sub format()

Dim s As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides

```
For Each oSh In s.Shapes
    If oSh.HasTable Then
        Set oTbl = oSh.Table
        For lRow = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
            For lCol = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
                With oTbl.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                    .Font.Name = "Batang"
                    .Font.Size = 16
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Next s

End Sub