# exporting dynamic range in excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, loops, powerpoint

I am new to linking excel with other apps, and was wondering if there is a way for me to copy and paste my spreadsheet into ppt slides? only thing is, I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of rows. I'm looking for a way to loop through and paste the spreadsheet in chunks of 15 per slide, along with the header of the table. is there any way to do that? the psuedo code I have in my mind is something like:

```
k=last row
for (i=0;i<k;i+15)
tbl.Row(i):tbl.Row(i+15) select
selection.copy into new ppt slide
```

this is what I have so far:

```
    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While i < 3
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableAll")
'Copy Range from Excel
  Set Rng = tbl.Rows((i), (i + 4)).Range

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'Add a slide to the Presentation   


  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

'Copy Excel Range
  Rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    'Set position:
      myShape.Left = 66
      myShape.Top = 152

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a recommendation - create or get the PowerPoint instance outside your `Do` loop. Same goes for `Set tbl...`, `Application.ScrenUpdating = False` - i.e. anything that should be done only once and not repeatedly.

Comment: thanks, i'll keep that out of my loop, but how can i have it select every nth-n+10 rows?

Comment: Do you want the header and each set of 15 rows to be pasted as one image? Also, with your pseudocode - you want to make sure that `i+15 < k`, not `i < k`, right? Also, I don't see where you have `k` or its equivalent in your current code.

Comment: yes I want exactly that, the header with every 15 rows. It would be cool if I can get it to paste as a table instead of an image, but that's not a big issue. you're right it should be i+15<k. k is just equal to the last row number. if there's 500 rows, then k is 500. i pasted a formula which calculates the last row for me and set the value of that cell to k

Comment: If you want them as one image, maybe hide rows as you're copying/pasting? I.e. copy header and rows 1-15, paste, then hide rows1-15, copy header and rows 16-30, etc.

Comment: the logic makes sense, but how would I code that?

Comment: I'd record a macro first, see if you can modify the code, and come back with any questions.

Comment: `Range("TableAll[[#Headers],[Application Name]]").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range("A1:N16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Rows("2:16").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("A1:N31").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False`

this is what i get when I record the macro, it can repeat until the end of the table, but how can i have it dynamic instead of sayifn A1:N16 everytime

Answer (score 1):

The approach you've taken is to copy then paste an **image** of the table into a PowerPoint slide. What this will force you to do is to create a copy of your table into a separate area of Excel, then sucessively reshape (i.e. delete rows) to create a table that is appropriate for the next slide. Then copy/PasteSpecial (as image) onto the PowerPoint slide.

My approach here is to copy the original Excel table, and then copy it to PowerPoint as a `PowerPoint.Table`. Now you have a shape that you can format and manipulate in PowerPoint as much as you want.

The tricky bit when deleting rows in a table (or range), is that often it's best to start deleting from the bottom in order to keep track of the row numbers/count.

My test data in Excel starts out looking like this:

[image]

The total number of rows in my test set is 56. I've got a column for the expected slide number. The block coloring is just to make it easy to see during debugging.

So the pseudocode is

```
copy the Excel table
set the "show area" to the top set of rows in the table
loop
    create a new slide
    copy the whole Excel table onto the slide
    delete all rows below "show area"
    delete all rows above the "show area"
    recalculate the next show area for the next slide
    exit the loop if the last slide is done
end loop
```

After building the code to process with that logic, my Excel table was transferred into a PowerPoint presentation and the slides ended up looking like this:

[image]

Using copy/paste in the manner still retains (mostly) the formatting of the original Excel table. The exception is that the font size is automatically reduced (at least in my PowerPoint settings). Therefore I needed to reset the font and the column widths to achieve the desired table format. Your settings may be different.

One other note: I assumed that you'd want the header row of the table to be duplicated on each slide. (this is how I'd want it)

Here's the full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateSlidesFromData()
    Const ROWS_PER_SLIDE As Long = 15

    '--- here's our data
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableAll")

    '--- attach to an existing PowerPoint instance or open a new one
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
        Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '--- now we can create a presentation with a slide (title only)
    Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

    '--- so copy the whole table to the clipboard...
    tbl.Range.Copy

    '--- ... and now loop to copy the table...
    Dim slideCount As Long
    slideCount = 1

    '--- must initialize these outside the loop
    Dim startingRowAboveGroupToDelete As Long
    Dim lastRowToDeleteBelow As Long
    startingRowAboveGroupToDelete = 0
    lastRowToDeleteBelow = startingRowAboveGroupToDelete + ROWS_PER_SLIDE + 1

    Dim lastSlide As Boolean
    lastSlide = False
    Do While True
        '--- add a new slide and paste the whole thing as a PowerPoint table shape
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(slideCount, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
        mySlide.Shapes.Paste

        '--- now get the table shape to work with
        '    (probably could be broken out into a function)
        Dim slideTable As PowerPoint.Table
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To mySlide.Shapes.Count
            If mySlide.Shapes(i).HasTable Then
                Set slideTable = mySlide.Shapes(i).Table
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        '--- first delete all the rows BELOW the group on this slide
        Debug.Print "Slide " & slideCount & ", deleting up to row " & lastRowToDeleteBelow
        For i = slideTable.Rows.Count To lastRowToDeleteBelow Step -1
            slideTable.Rows(i).Delete
        Next i

        '--- now delete all rows ABOVE the group that should be shown on this slide
        Debug.Print "Slide " & slideCount & ", start deleting above at row " & startingRowAboveGroupToDelete
        For i = startingRowAboveGroupToDelete To 2 Step -1
            slideTable.Rows(i).Delete
        Next i

        '--- finally a little formatting
        ChangeTableFont slideTable, "Arial", 12
        Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
        With slideTable
            .Columns(1).Width = 140
            .Columns(2).Width = 200
            .Columns(3).Width = 80
            .Columns(4).Width = 160
            .Columns(5).Width = 80
            Set shp = .Parent
            shp.Top = 200
            shp.Left = 50
            Debug.Print mySlide.Name & "(" & shp.Name & "): table position: left=" & shp.Left & ", top=" & shp.Top
        End With

        If lastSlide Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        '--- calculate for the next loop, which also checks to see if we're done
        slideCount = slideCount + 1
        startingRowAboveGroupToDelete = (ROWS_PER_SLIDE * (slideCount - 1)) - (slideCount - 2)
        lastRowToDeleteBelow = startingRowAboveGroupToDelete + ROWS_PER_SLIDE

        '--- add a new slide and (maybe) go back around
        If lastRowToDeleteBelow > tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
            '--- the next slide is the last slide
            lastSlide = True
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Sub ChangeTableFont(ByRef slideTable As PowerPoint.Table, _
                    ByVal fontName As String, _
                    ByVal fontSize As Long)
    '--- based on an answer by Steve Rindsberg
    '    https://stackoverflow.com/a/31822059/4717755
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    For lRow = 1 To slideTable.Rows.Count
        For lCol = 1 To slideTable.Columns.Count
            With slideTable.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                .Font.Name = fontName
                .Font.Size = fontSize
            End With
        Next lCol
    Next lRow
End Sub
```