# Using VBA, Changing text Color in transferring data from XLSM to PPTX

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerpoint, excel-2010

I wrote the below macro in VBA to copy data from Excel and then paste it into the last slide of a table in my powerpoint deck. The challenge that I'm running into is that I'm getting an error on when I am trying to change the text color from the default white to black.

```
shpTable.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong on this line? All else works well.

```
Option Explicit

Dim myFile, Fileselected As String, Path As String, objPPT As Object
Dim ppApp   As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres  As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim shpTable As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Sub Button1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose Template PPT File."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
    Fileselected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Path = Fileselected

Dim i As Integer

Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
i = 1

ppApp.Presentations.Open Filename:=Path  ' 'PowerPointFile = "C:\Test.pptx"
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Item(i)

' for debug
Debug.Print ppPres.Name

'ppPres.Slides(1).Copy
'ppPres.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add Index:=ppPres.Slides.Count + 1 'changed paste to add

'Set NewSlide = PowPntApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutTitle)

Set activeSlide = ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=(ppPres.Slides.Count + 1), Layout:=ppLayoutTitle)

Set activeSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppPres.Slides.Count)

activeSlide.Select
Set shpTable = activeSlide.Shapes.AddTable(3, 3)
shpTable.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("F5")
shpTable.Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("F6")

shpTable.Select
shpTable.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 211, 211)
shpTable.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set ppPres = Nothing
Set ppApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice how you are updating the `RGB` property of `shpTable.Fill.ForeColor`? You'll need to target the `.RGB` property on the `shpTable.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color` property like so:

```
shpTable.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 211, 211)
shpTable.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

That should fix your problem!

Comment: Still doesn't work. Getting "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The specified value is out of range"

Comment: I'm using excel/powerpoint 2010

Comment: Based on my research, Powerpoint does not let you update the entire tables font in one line of code. The workaround is to count the table range and loop through each cell updating individually. The code for one cell would be as follows: shpTable.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)  To loop, would need to combine it with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821984/formatting-table-in-powerpoint-macro

Comment: That is interesting.  I'm glad you found that resource and hopefully it helps!